# How to get data with async func?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

Ok, I have async function, which get data about cryptocurrency. And when I load page at first time, data is undefined. But, if I change something in code (for example: set insignificant Enter) data is appears.

How change my code to get data with statr page?

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const resCoins = []
      for (let coinName of coinsName){
        let coin = await axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/' + coinName)
        resCoins.push(coin.data)
      }

      let usd = {symbol: 'usd', market_data: {current_price: {}}}
      for (let currency of resCoins){
        usd.market_data.current_price[currency.id] =  1 / currency.market_data.current_price.usd
      }
      resCoins.push(usd)

      setCoins(resCoins);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Do you use getData in `useEffect`?

Comment: Yes, I use this after create getData function

Answer (score 0):

For is a sync operation. They will not wait for response. So you need to use Promise.all()

```
const resCoins = await Promise.all(
  coinsName.map(
    (coinName) =>
      axios
        .get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/" + coinName)
        .then((res) => res.data)
  )
)
```

[More Info](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404)

Comment: every `await` and `async` is unecessary in your code, you can remove it

Comment: @Ifaruki , Not every (Only in .map). Thanks